# hive analyze query taking lot of time

Tags: performance, hadoop, hive, query-tuning, apache-tez

In order to speed up ETL queries on large tables, we run many `analyze` queries on these tables and date columns in the evening.
but these `analyze` queries on columns take lot of memory and time.
we are using tez.
is there any way to optimize `analyze` query also like some set commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are loading tables using insert overwrite then statistics can be gathered automatically by setting `hive.stats.autogather=true` during insert overwrite queries.

If the table is partitioned and partitions are being loaded incrementally, then you can analyze only last partitions.

```
ANALYZE TABLE [db_name.]tablename [PARTITION(partcol1[=val1], partcol2[=val2], ...)]
```

See examples here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/StatsDev

For ORC files it's possible to specify `hive.stats.gather.num.threads` to incraase parallelism.

See full list of statistic settings here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties#ConfigurationProperties-Statistics